# Texturise text support Firefox , Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Texturise text support Firefox , Chrome

How to create text texturise on css or js use!

create text texturise support Firefox , Chrome

HELP ME

Answer (score 0):

Use mask-image.
    -webkit-mask-image: url(images/ur-image.png);
    -o-mask-image: url(images/ur-image.png);
    -moz-mask-image: url(images/ur-image.png);
    -ms-mask-image: url(images/ur-image.png);
    mask-image: url(images/ur-image.png);
Create a texture you need in photoshop and save it as png with transparency ticked when saving for web.
Check this link. You will get the idea.
http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/texturise-web-type-css

Comment: Thanks ! But not support Firefox

Answer (score 0):

This is only supported in Webkit browsers, but I think it is what you're looking for:
http://css-tricks.com/image-under-text/